# Django ORM leaves opened connections

Tags: postgresql, django-models, connection

I'm using django ORM with Postgres. 
After any operations with models (e.g. simple select) in postgres appears new opened connection in IDLE state.

I've tried all possible transaction manipulations, I've tried calling

```
connection.close()
```

manually. All useless.
And sooner or later, I'm recieveing "FATAL:  connection limit exceeded for non-superusers" message.

What can I've made wrong?

Comment: What are you doing with the ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, false alarm. It's normal behavior for PGPool, which was involved for this DB.